# How can I find code with a specific string, but not in comments

Tags: sql-server, regex

I'm trying to search through 1,000's of stored procedures and functions for a particular string (in this case an email address), but I want to ignore it when it's in a comment block.

This is the SQL syntax to find the objects, but there are hundreds of results and I don't want to go through each one to determine if the email address is being utilized in code or just in a comment block.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  o.name objectname
FROM sys.sql_modules m
  INNER JOIN sys.objects o 
    ON m.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE definition LIKE '%somebody@somewhere.com%'
ORDER BY o.name
```

I have a CLR library (SQLSharp) where I can use regex, but I'm not sure of the regex expression that would identify a comment vs valid code.

For those who are RegEx savvy and not SQL Server savvy, a comment is defined as a single line starting with two dashes (e.g. --) or multiple lines starting with /* and ending with */

Just the thought of trying to figure this out makes my brain hurt.

Comment: You cannot really do this with regex. My solution would be to pass the results to Perl or awk and refine them by trimming out comments. If the comments are always line-internal you could even do it in `sed`. `sql whatwever | perl -0777pe 's%/\*.*?\*/%%gs' | fgrep somebody@somewhere.com`

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't eliminate the email address from comments too? If the email address is no longer being used, the comments containing it are not valid either—bad! With that as a preamble, I'd use your existing query to generate the list of procedures to examine in more detail. Then I'd collect the data (object name and description) in a file, and analyze them in detail. The detailed analysis can include stripping comments more easily. The `-- to EOL` comments are easy to remove. Multiline `/* ... */` comments are not so easy (but the SQL version is a lot simpler than the C version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the code I posted in an article on SQL Server Central:

[Searching Objects for Text](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stored+Procedures/62975/)

The Stored Procedure described in that article has the ability to not only ignore both inline (`--`) and block (`/* ... */`) comments, but it can also ignore text within single quotes.  The code defaults the option to ignore comments to True as it seems unlikely to want to search for non-impacting text.  But the default for ignoring strings is False as dynamic SQL and some other text that can go into a string might still be valid, executable code in the end.

The code was developed for SQL Server 2000 and hence does not make use of `NVARCHAR(MAX)` in 1 or 2 places that would really help.  I have since updated the code to use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead of `NVARCHAR(4000)` and hence a single temp table, but have not updated the article with those changes.  I will try to do that one of these days.  And I believe the code in the article looks at one database whereas the updated code will look through all accessible DBs if one is not specified.

Comment: Shouldn't refer to a link as the sole basis of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to identify both kinds of comments

```
(--.*?\n)|(/\*.*?\*/)
```

Make sure `.` matches newline too to identify multi line comments

Note that, on some systems, `\r` is treated as line break character and on some a combination of `\r\n` is the line break character.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the parser component of my ModuleStore project, which creates a syntax tree from the SQL you pass in. This tree can then be queried and modified programatically.

http://code.google.com/p/bsn-modulestore/